# Setting a variable for a Z SQL method

Tags: sql, plone, zope

In Plone I have a Z SQL methood:

```
SELECT [aapp_qtitle]
      ,[aapp_mtitle]
      ,[aapp_sdate]
      ,[aapp_duration]
FROM [AAPP].[dbo].[M_PageBodyElement] where [aapp_id]=<dtml-sqlvar aapp_id type=int>
```

How can I set the value of aapp_id in my Plone page code?

OK thanks Matthew what's the exact template code?  I've tried:

```
<p tal:define="AAPPInfo python:here.get/AAPPInfo(aapp_id=100003).dictionaries()"></p>
<p tal:repeat="records context/AAPPInfo">
<span tal:replace="records/aapp_qtitle">Title: </span><br>
```

But I get name 'AAPPInfo' is not defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ZSQL method was called 'getAAPPInfo', for example, you would call it from Python like this:

```
AAPPInfo = context.getAAPPInfo(aapp_id=1).dictionaries()
if AAPPInfo:
  print AAPPInfo[0]['aapp_qtitle']
```

or similar.

From a Page Template you need to use the expression `tal:define="AAPPInfo python:here.getAAPPInfo(aapp_id=1).dictionaries()` and then you can iterate through that as normal.

Answer (score 0):

AAPPInfo was a guess at what you called your SQL method.  You also have ignored my syntax and written your own, that's why it's not working.

Comment: The SQL method is called AAPPInfo, so that's OK.  If I put in <tal:define="AAPPInfo python:here.getAAPPInfo(aapp_id=1).dictionaries()> I get a compilation  failed EOF in middle of construct...

Comment: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Z-SQL-methods-with-explicit-arguments-in-ZTP-tp5138564p5138564.html