# Plone Accessing Z SQL Method from script

Tags: python, plone

We are trying to add a z sql method to access the database. We have already done this and tested it. However, when following instructions about how to access the method in a script ([Setting a variable for a Z SQL method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964467/setting-a-variable-for-a-z-sql-method) and http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/RelationalDatabases.html), the script fails with this error in the instance log:

AttributeError: MethodName

This is when calling : context.MethodName

The function is intended for use in a customized 'portal_skins/plone_scripts'

Using: Plone 4.2.6

Anyone have a clue?

```
2014-01-24T12:48:16 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1390585696.260.938992561119            http://foo.com/mail_password
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 5, in mail_password
    - <CustomizedPythonScript at /mail_password>
    - Line 5
  Module AccessControl.ImplPython, line 675, in guarded_getattr
AttributeError: InsertMessage
```

The insert message is called : context.InsertMessage(variables) in 'portal_skins/plone_scripts/mail_password' script

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While many of us would be happy to help answer your question, we are much more likely to understand the problem if you provide the specific code you're using as well as the full traceback.

Comment: InsertMessage is coming from somewhere. Does that have security declarations to connect its use with a permission that the user has on context?

Comment: If you mean 'Insert Message/manage_access', then anonymous user has 'Use Database Methods' checked and still does't work.

Comment: or rename your script and see you can access it via code or not ?